# kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <SignUp>

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Hi I'm trying to include a kivy class in another kv file but it gives an issue saying that it can't find the class. Can you help me? I'm desperate :(

Here's the code of the two files

constructor.kv

```
#:include Constructor/signup.kv

WindowManager:
    SignUpPage:

<SignUpPage>:
    name: "signup"
    SignUp: #here gives the issue because it can't find the class in signup.kv
```

signup.kv

```
<SignUp>
    id: SignUp

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Email:"
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .8}

        TextInput:
            font_size:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .7}

        Label:
            text: "Password:"
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .6}

        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .5}

        Button:
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .3}
            text: "Submit"

        Button:
            size_hint: .4, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .1}
            text: "Hai già un account? Accedi qui!"
            on_release: app.root.current = "login"
```

Comment: Where are the `SignUpPage` and `SignUp` classes defined. Note that your `.kv` files do not define those classes.

Comment: ok so i only have to define the class in python code?

Comment: Not saying that, but they must be defined somewhere.